# Some data returns undefined using RTK Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose, react-redux, redux-toolkit

This is my first time using Redux, what happens is that I am trying to show data in a Material UI Select, and when I show the user name it works perfectly, I did the same for the partner's data, but they arrived as undefined.

In the server index, I have the following code:
`app.use("/client", clientRoutes);`

In the Routes I have this:

```
import express from "express";
import { getAllUsers, getPartner } from "../controllers/client.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/users", getAllUsers);
router.get("/partners", getPartner);

export default router;
```

In the controller this:

```
import User from "../models/User.js";
import Partner from "../models/Partner.js";

export const getAllUsers = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find();
    res.status(200).json(users);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};

export const getPartner = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const partners = await Partner.find();
    res.status(200).json(partners);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

In the model this:

```js
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const PartnerSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    partner_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 2,
      max: 100,
    },
    partner_phone: {
      type: String,
      min: 2,
      max: 100,
    },
    partner_user: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 2,
      max: 100,
    },
    partner_password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 2,
      max: 100,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const Partner = mongoose.model("Partner", PartnerSchema);
export default Partner;
```

In the api this:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const api = createApi({
  reducerPath: "adminApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL }),
  tagTypes: ["User", "Users", "Partners"],
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getUser: build.query({
      query: (id) => `general/user/${id}`,
      providesTags: ["User"],
    }),
    getAllUsers: build.query({
      query: () => "client/users",
      providesTags: ["Users"],
    }),
    getPartner: build.query({
      query: () => "client/partners",
      providesTags: ["Partners"],
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetUserQuery, useGetAllUsersQuery, useGetPartnerQuery } = api;
```

and in my component the following imports::

```
import { useGetAllUsersQuery } from "state/api";
import { useGetPartnerQuery } from "state/api";
```

and then this code:

```
  const { data } = useGetAllUsersQuery();
  const { data2 } = useGetPartnerQuery();
  console.log("usuarios", data);
  console.log("partners", data2);
```

That's where I realize that the data arrives undefined.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPl4N.png)

Thank you very much to those who can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the line of

```
const { data } = useGetAllUsersQuery();
```

You are properly destructuring the `data` property, but the **issue** is that on the following line of

```
const { data2 } = useGetPartnerQuery()
```

You are destructuring non-existant `data2` property which has value `undefined`, instead you should be destructuring `data` property and rename it to `data2` using colon

```
const { data: data2 } = useGetPartnerQuery()
```